# text encoding not readable on linux

Tags: encode, samtools

I have a text file which has been previously readable in linux, then I modified some names in it manually on windows and now when I am running it on linux (using samtools), it cannot find exactly those names that I have changed manually

```
[faidx] Failed to fetch sequence in Mariner-1_Dhyd-L#DNA/Tc1-Mariner
```

I suspect this is the windows to linux problem?
the current encoding of the file is

```
file -i filname.lib
filename.lib: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

then I tried to change it to Utf8

```
iconv -i us-ascii -t UTF8 filename.lib > filname-encode.lib
```

though the file encoding has still remained the same and still same errors.
how should I fix it

Comment: It would be helpful to know what tool(s) you used to "modify some names manually on Windows", as well as the original encoding of the file. Some Windows editors add a Byte Order Mark (BOM) sequence to the beginning of the file, which can confuse other tools. If the file now contains a mix of encodings, you may need to go back to the original file, but I'm a little surprised everything isn't just ASCII.

Comment: I used notepad for manual modification. I checked the whole encoding line by line in notepad++ in case there is windows characters in it or there is extra space...thought surprisingly I didn't find any encoding problem, just removing the headers that were complained about fixed it!